# Routing - parameter as view name

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Is it possible to write a URL route in Django where view name will be dynamic (parsed from URL)?

```
"http://www.example.com/<view>/"  => executes app.views.<view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a view docked at `http://www.example.com/` with the view name as argument and then in the view function either fire apropriate handler from a dict `name` -> `custom view`, or scan `globals()` (ugly, you would end up checking the input for any malicious data since it's taken directly from users and `globals()` returns a dict of all global variables visible).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediate/help view.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^/(?P<view_name>\w+)/$', help_view),
```

views.py:

```
def help_view(request, view_name):
    return globals()[view_name]()
```

Or, instead of calling a function from `globals()` you can have a dictionary with `view_name->view_function` mapping.

Hope that helps.